# Run Method of an Activity from a class

Tags: java, android

I have a MainActivity, which sends (over an another classA) my "register/login/play" informations to my server.
The other ClassA gets the answer and sends these to classB where I implement the register()/login()/play() function.

My problem is these functions from classB have to call another method in MainActivity (like open PopUp or change layout). I searched for 5 hours now and the other examples on stackover doesnt help.

At least I found a solution like:

```
classB{  
MainActivity mA; 
...  
mA= (WelcomeActivity) this.getCurrentActivity();

    getCurrentActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mA.method();
        }
    });
...
}
```

Is that correct or can I find a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do *not* store references to Activities to call from other non-Android classes. You will end up with spaghetti code, violations of encapsulation, and memory leaks.

You need to provide mode code about the structure of your application and how "Class B" relates to your activity, but one suggestion based on your initial post would be to provide a callback in the "B" class that the main activity sets itself as in order to respond to the play action.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   // Somewhere in onCreate

    ClassB b = new ClassB();
    b.setOnPlayListener(new OnPlayListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlay() {
            // Respond to onPlay in this Activity
        }
    }   
}

public class B {
    public void play() {
        // Do stuff for playing
        mOnPlayListener.onPlay(); // Invoke callback to notify play is happening - this will be the activity
    }

    public void setOnPlayListener(OnPlayListener listener) {
        mOnPlayListener = listener;
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, ty for your answer. But I cant find the studios method in google. Was it an example? But it looks like an android studios library method.

Comment: I really don't get this example... A little help would be cool!

Comment: What don't you get? "A little help" doesn't tell me what you don't understand.

Comment: Sry, I am not that good in programming, so I can't express myself that good. I cant find object.setOnPlayListener! I googled it but can't find it on google neither.

Comment: That is not a real thing. I was a made up example based on your code (login(), register (), play () functions you mentioned). It's an interface you would define.

Comment: Ok, I will use runUI... what I wrote in the Question, but will check your answer, for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a general question, basically you can use interfaces and make the mainActivity implement them. It's called delegation.

More over you can use this pattern if you have activity and many fragment to communicate between all of them.

Read about delegation in android and SOLID in general.